# How can a git diff between a merge commit and one of its parents be empty?

Tags: git, merge, diff, git-diff

I am confused by this git commit log.
I think the relevant facts are in the screenshots below.
The screen shots are from source tree. But I get the same empty diffs if I run git diff on the command line.

[image: diff between 1 and 4]

[image: diff between 1 and 2]

(If i single select commit 4 the diff is also empty.)

What I can't understand is why the diff is empty between commit 1 and 4. Or why commit 4 which is a merge doesn't contain file differences.

Commit 2 introduces file changes to the purple branch, and I can't see how these would not be part of the diff between 1 and 4.

(Commit 3 is a merge from a branch that is a historic version of the leftmost branch (the trunk). So I don't think it makes sense to have it there; if it was a merge from the current state of the trunk it would allow the merge 4 to be a fast forward, now it's just a merge of a subset of the trunk.)

edit:
The workflow is git flow. So the lines to the right are feature branches and the leftmost is a develop branch to which the feature branches are merged.

Comment: Your screen captures are blurred and difficult to read, and your workflow is poorly-described and hard to follow.  Please update your question to make it more understandable.

Comment: I cant unblurr since i am not at liberty to publicly post the commit messages and filenames. I will update as per your request on the workflow. Thanks

Comment: Show us a diagram e.g. `A -- B -- C`

Comment: An other way to pose the question without getting into details about the workflow: how can possible two consecutive commits (1 and 4) contain no diff, when the second of the two is a merge of a commit that contains a history not part of the branch?

Comment: You should provide information about the commits/history prior to commit `1`! The following ones (after `4`) are not of interest. Also, what files have changed and how?

Answer (score 0):

My mistake. Actually I believe that according to my description of the situation it should not be possible that the merge at commit 4 would be empty, just like it should not be possible for the diff between 1 and 4 to be empty.
The explanation for why it was, was that commit 3, contrary to what I wrote, was not just a merge from a previous state of the develop branch. For some to me unknown reason, this merge commit actually reverted the file changes done by commit 2. And in this new light it's no longer strange that the diff is empty.

Sorry for have wasted your time on this.